# How can I set distinct-name on Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I try EJB invocations from a client to a server, they are actually same copied `ear` files each other and on same machine.
I think that I must set "distinct-name" in somewhere, but I can not find it.

[WildFly Developer Guide - EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI):

> **distinct-name** : This is a WildFly-specific name which can be optionally assigned to the deployments that are deployed on the server. More about the purpose and usage of this will be explained in a separate chapter. If a deployment doesn't use distinct-name then, use an empty string in the JNDI name, for distinct-name

Where is "*a separate chapter*"?

Comment: Having an empty distinct name does not appear to work in JBOSS 
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `<distinct-name>` attribute in [jboss-app.xml](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.0.0.Final/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/ejb/remote/distinctname/jboss-app.xml)(EAR) or [jboss-ejb3.xml](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.0.0.Final/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/ejb/remote/distinctname/jboss-ejb3.xml)(WAR/EJB jar).